# How to use fflush in c on OS/X

Tags: c, macos, fflush

[program source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoEcW.png)How should I use `fflush` in C on OS/X? When I use it, it does not clear my buffer and terminates the program straight away.

Comment: Don't tell me you fflush-ed on `stdin`.... it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Please show us your code as a [mcve] (or buy us all crystal balls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `fflush(stdin);` invokes undefined behavior.  You should not use this to *flush* characters from the standard input buffer.  Instead, you can read the characters upto the next linefeed and ignore them:

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
    continue;
```

You can also use `scanf()` for this, but it is tricky:

```
scanf("%*^[\n]");  // read and discard any characters different from \n
scanf("%*c");      // read and discard the next char, which, if present, is a \n
```

Note that you cannot combine the 2 calls above because it would fail to read a linefeed non preceded by any other characters, as the first format would fail.